# Angular can't remove focus outline from a Boostrap custom checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

For whatever odd reason, Angular does not blur out the clicked element, so I 'fixed' it like this:

```
*:focus { outline: none !important; }
```

It's not a real fix, instead every element should be blurred automatically, but I'm not sure how to do that without a directive, so this must do for now, unless someone has a better solution.

However, I can't seem to apply the same 'fix' for Bootstrap custom checkboxes.

```
<label class="c-input c-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="c-indicator"></span>
    Remember Me
</label>
```

This is how it looks like when focused:

[image: Unchecked]
[image: Checked]

I tried removing outline, border, box-shadow - nothing seemed to work.

Comment: `.c-checkbox input:focus {outline: none !important}` doesn't work? Consider reproducing the problem in jsfiddle so we can see what's happening

Comment: I was just trying that with StackOverflow snippet, oddly enough this doesn't happen. I'm using Bootstrap v4 Alpha and AngularJS Stable v1.4.8. I'm sure it has nothing to do with my custom css rules. And no, it does not fix it..

Comment: There HAVE to be another library doing that, because that's not angular/bootstrap fault as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/8dsc2ccu/1

Comment: I have the following items included: Google font, Bootstrap v4 Alpha, Font Awesome 4.5.0, Angular Stable v1.4.8 minified, Angular Animate, Angular UI-Router, Angular UI-Bootstrap and nothing else. Additionally html5 mode enabled and writing document location to base href.

Comment: No, it has to be your custom css then. Do you know how to use Chrome Developers tools and inspectors? As you can see here, all of those libraries are coexisting and yet, I can not reproduce the outline you talk about. So it has nothing to do with those libraries. http://jsfiddle.net/8dsc2ccu/3/

Comment: The focus 'not disappearing' was there from the beginning, even when I didn't have any CSS written at all. I'm getting really frustrated and depressed over this simple thing... Here's all of my CSS regardless, not that much written yet: http://pastebin.com/fc2hYgp9

Comment: You sure it's outline and not `box-shadow`?

Comment: It does look like box-shadow, but that makes no difference either. Tried forcing with `!important`, but nothing... I'm about to give up, this is just silly..

Comment: Finally! Forcing box-shadow none with !important worked when added to .c-input .c-indicator... What a struggle, sorry for wasting time of everyone who tried to help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem coming from your libraries, but your custom css. You have to be missing something, but this code should work.
Place it at the end of your custom css file.

```
.c-input .c-indicator {
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important
}
```

Comment: Nope, still nothing.. I've uploaded all of my css on pastebin and linked it in a comment to question, if you could take a look, please.